# YouTube API v3 Check Video Processing Status

Tags: c#, youtube, youtube-api, youtube.net-api, youtube-data-api

Once the video is uploaded, how to check its processing status using C# .NET's API?
The answer should be in the [Google.Apis.Youtube.v3.Data.VideoProcessingDetails](http://www.deskcenter.info/YouTube-Api/google-youtube-v3-rev48-csharp-1.3.0-beta-doc/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Youtube_1_1v3_1_1Data_1_1VideoProcessingDetails.html), but how exactly should that object be instantiated? The following code throws a System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException:

```
video.ProcessingDetails = new VideoProcessingDetails();
```

The code above is being used in the following context:

```
 UserCredential credential;
 using (FileStream stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
 {
        credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube, YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore("YouTube.Auth.Store")).Result;
 }
 var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
 {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
  });

  var video = new Video();
  video.Snippet = new VideoSnippet();
  video.Snippet.Title = Title;
  video.Snippet.Description = Description;
  video.Snippet.Tags = Tags;
  video.ProcessingDetails = new VideoProcessingDetails(); // Here it throws an exception
  video.Snippet.CategoryId = CategotyId;
  video.Status = new VideoStatus();
  video.Status.PrivacyStatus = PrivacyStatus;
  var filePath = FilePath;
```

The idea, is once the video is uploaded, check in a loop if the video is still processing and perform other operations on it once the processing is done.

UPDATE: I figured out that if the object is instantiated after the video is uploaded (i.e. in the **private static void videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived()** method, for example), the exception is gone, but once I try accessing video.**ProcessingDetails.ProcessingProgress.TimeLeftMs.Value**, it says that that value is null.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In my own work, I have found that when *ProcessingDetails.ProcessingStatus* equals "terminated", all of the other properties in *ProcessingDetails* are equal to nothing (i.e. null). I believe that this means that YouTube has finished processing the video.

I usually check a Google API v3 property to see if it is null before attempting to use it.